# array_walk_recursive return value

Tags: php, arrays

I using array recursive to find leaf. My function is working, I easy printing value from leaf. Now i trying get value out of function, i need use this for another function. This is my code.

```
$nazwa;     
function testArrayItem($item, $key)
    {
        if($key== "values")
        {
            $nazwa=$item;
        }
    }

    array_walk_recursive($des1['values']['0'], 'testArrayItem');
echo $nazwa;
```

My varible "$nazwa" is empty how i can get value from my function?
Thx for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had the same problem as you did. But defining the variable as global is not correct in any case. Look at my answer on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24751543/passing-user-data-as-reference-to-array-walk-recursive-in-php/24751830#24751830).